# To check logic in statements which is in a word document

Tags: c#, .net

How to check IF, Then, Else and End If condition which is in word document using c#

Please suggest me some code...or help me with the logic.
Thanks in advance..

```
Stack stackWords = new Stack();
string[] words = SplitWords(sLine);

foreach(string s in words)
{
    if(s.Contains("IF") || s.Contains("ELSE") ||  (sLine.Contains("THEN")) || (sLine.Contains("ENDIF")))
    {
        for (; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i] == "IF" || words[i] == "ELSE" ||
            words[i] == "ELSEIF" || words[i] == "THEN" || words[i] == "END IF")
            {
                stackWords.Push(words[i]);
            }
        }
       // stackWords.Push(s);
    }
  //  MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I have tried something likr this...but am sure It won't work for long document...

Comment: Why do you have two for-loops ?

Comment: @SonerGönül waiting for ur reply...

Comment: Coz sLine contains a line (takes from the document)

Comment: What library are you using for reading the lines in the file? Are you trying to validate any syntax or are you only collecting matches of these exact words?

Comment: using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
yeah trying to validate syntax which is in a word document...
If there is any mismatch I have to put it in a .txt file

Comment: I have a hard time seeing what exactly you are trying to do. You split the line into words and then you still check the line for then/endif.  Can there be and IF and ENDIF on the same line?  Or how does your input text look?

Comment: IF (tactical_dc884KnobFocusCopilot = ‘FOCUS VREF’)
     THEN
       tactical_dc884KnobFocusCopilot# = ‘NONE’
     ENDIF
   
IF (vspeedModeV2Pilot = ‘vspeed state 2’)
   THEN
     vspeedModeV2Pilot# = ‘vspeed state 1’
   ENDIF

   IF (vspeedModeVrPilot = ‘vspeed state 2’)
   THEN
     vspeedModeVrPilot# = ‘vspeed state 1’
   ENDIF

   IF (vspeedModeVsePilot = ‘vspeed state 2’)
   THEN
     vspeedModeVsePilot# = ‘vspeed state 1’
   ENDIF   

   IF (vspeedModeV1Pilot = ‘vspeed state 2’)
   THEN
     vspeedModeV1Pilot# = ‘vspeed state 1’
   ENDIF


my input text looks like this..

Comment: Please post the code inside the question's content, not in the comments...

Comment: Ofcoure the text is in different lines...I have copied and pasted it..

Comment: @AlexFilipovici that is not code it is input text...

Comment: Ye Unfortunately the commentfield isnt very happy about linebreaks. If you would put it in the question as code it would be awsome :)

Comment: @Evelie CAN U Please suggest me something ...:(

Comment: Yes Im trying to help you. But thing is I cant figure out what you are trying to do. That's why I ask you all these questions :(

Comment: If you only want to iterate all words and put the "IF" "THEN" "ELSE" "ENDIF" on the stack sure it would be easy. But since you are checking the line for words aswel I suspect your question is not that simple. Right?

Comment: I want to check if there are any logical mismatches in IF ELSE THEN ENDIF conditions which is in a word document... @Evelie

Comment: @Evelie ...yes u r right ...It is not simple...I have been trying from 2 dayz.. :(

Comment: So basicly you want to pull out these and put them on a stack. And later check if it's logically correct?

Comment: @Evelie yes U got it...!! that's what I hv been trying to do...Can we do it like that ...or is there any other way do it..??

Comment: Ive provided you with a solution. Let me know how it works out or if I need to change anything.

Comment: You really don't want to implement a scripting language in Word. Word, like any document generator, should only print data in places you assign, and you should fill the data from code. The idea behind those scripting languages always is _"Then the client can change their report templates"_, which they never do and which always comes back to the developer, who then wishes he just solved it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get yourself and enum with the values. Easier to handle than strings.

```
    public enum Vals
    {
        IF,
        THEN,
        ENDIF,
        ELSE,
    }
```

We have a method for comparing if the next value is correct pair with the current.

```
    public static bool IsValidFollower(Vals val1, Vals val2)
    {
        if (val1 == Vals.IF)
            return val2 == Vals.THEN;
        if (val1 == Vals.THEN)
            return val2 == Vals.ENDIF;
        if (val1 == Vals.ENDIF)
            return val2 == Vals.IF || val2 == Vals.ELSE;
        if (val1 == Vals.ELSE)
            return val2 == Vals.THEN;
        return false;
    }
```

And then instead of stack we use a normal list. (Just a personal preference, I dont want them in reverse order)

```
        List<Vals> ListWords = new List<Vals>();

        foreach (string str in s.Split(' '))
        {
            if (str.Contains("ENDIF"))
                ListWords.Add(Vals.ENDIF);

            else if (str.Contains("ELSE"))
                ListWords.Add(Vals.ELSE);

            else if (str.Contains("THEN"))
                ListWords.Add(Vals.THEN);

            else if (str.Contains("IF"))
                ListWords.Add(Vals.IF);
        }
```

When we have the list of all the values. We check if they are logically valid.

```
        bool valid = true;
        for (int i = ListWords.Count - 1; i +1< ListWords.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!IsValidFollower(ListWords[i], ListWords[i + 1]))
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: ENDIF will come after IF in the conditons statement.... :(

Comment: Yes but if you only want to put them on your stack it doesnt matter.. And then you use your stack for then logic check.

Comment: yes, that's what am not getting. Checking logic after inserting into the stack...also there will be problem with IF and ENDIF ...while checking logic

Comment: But this solves the put right things on the stack ?

Comment: Yeah, but how can we check for the condition then...like for one if there should be only one endIf and for every if there should be one Then also after else there must be EndIF.....:(

Comment: Updated the solution with a complete solution. Tell me how it works out

Comment: sure I will get Back once It works...

Comment: Can Please explain me the last content....from bool valid = true; to...!!

Comment: Valid is if the document is valid. Then he loops all the values and checks for something that isnt valid. If IsValidFollower returns false that means that the following value to the current index is incorrect logically. Which will result in valid = false and a break on the loop.

Comment: So he starts with assuming that the document is valid. Then he looks for something thats not correct. If he finds something bad he lets valid to false

Comment: @Evelie, I like your approach of using an `Enum` and a validation method. But I would like to suggest some logic improvements for the method and a better exception tracking mechanism. Should I include that in my answer so you would update your answer (if you consider it necessary), or should I edit your answer?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici yOU CAN EDIT THE ANSWER OR YOU COULD POST AN OTHER ONE...

Comment: Either way is good for me. But I wanted to keep it as simple as possible so he later on can improve with his own code. :)

Comment: @Evelie It works fine for if the document has if else then endif.
But what if document has a condition some thing like this 
IF()
THEN
ELSE()
  IF()
  THEN
   ELSEIF()
ENdIF
ENDIF

Comment: As alex mentioned the logiccheck can be improved. For that you could use something like a counter how many ifstatements he have gone through. Im not here to make the complete code for you ;)

Comment: @CharanPrudhvi glad I could be to some help. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Evelie's answer, here's a working sample program which does the checking (I believe that I covered some cases in the validation method and I also added some tracking of the faulty keyword in the sequence).

**Remark:** If this is helping, please mark @Evelie's answer as **the answer**. I just posted this for you to make an impression of the whole set.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stack stackWords = new Stack();

        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var file = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\doc.docx";
        var document = app.Documents.Open(file);

        try
        {
            int count = document.Words.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                string text = document.Words[i].Text.Trim().ToUpper();
                Vals val;
                if(Enum.TryParse<Vals>(text, out val))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
                    if (stackWords.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var peeked = (Vals)stackWords.Peek();
                        if (IsValidFollower(peeked, val))
                        {
                            stackWords.Push(val);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception(String.Format("Exception occured at word {0}. {1} was not expected after {2}",i, val, peeked));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stackWords.Push(val);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Syntax sequence is valid");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Syntax sequence is invalid");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            document.Close();
            app.Quit();
        }

    }

    public enum Vals
    {
        IF,
        THEN,
        ENDIF,
        ELSE,
        ELSEIF
    }

    public static bool IsValidFollower(Vals val1, Vals val2)
    {
        if (val1 == Vals.IF)
            return val2 == Vals.THEN;
        if (val1 == Vals.THEN)
            return val2 == Vals.ENDIF || val2 == Vals.ELSEIF || val2 == Vals.ELSE;
        if (val1 == Vals.ENDIF)
            return val2 == Vals.IF;
        if (val1 == Vals.ELSE)
            return val2 == Vals.ENDIF;
        if (val1 == Vals.ELSEIF)
            return val2 == Vals.THEN;
        return false;
    }
```